# PHP script not writing data to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

After polishing a bug with the includes, I am trying now to make this script to write to the database but after submitting the form, the page goes blank ( obviously ) but no data is written to the database. There is no error, nor in firebug or the nginx logs. I have also tested with "php -l" to find type errors but the sintax is correct in all files. How can I further debug a PHP script ?

```
<?php

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/db.php";

if ($_POST['fSubmit'] == "Submit") {
    $varName = $_POST['Name'];
    $varSurname = $_POST['Surname'];
    $varMail = $_POST['Mail'];
    $varCountry = $_POST['Country'];
    $varCity = $_POST['City'];
    $varAddress = $_POST['Address'];
    $varPO = $_POST['PO'];
    $varPass = $_POST['Pass'];
    $varCpass = $_POST['Cpass'];
    try {
        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $DBH->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");


        $STH = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'password', 'email' )"
                . "VALUES ('$varName', '$varPass', '$varMail')";
        $count = $DBH->exec($sql);

        $DBH = null; //disconnect
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }




}
if($count !== false) echo 'Number of rows added: '. $count;
?>
```

**EDIT**

I got "trying to execute an empty query on line 22" on the nginx log now.

Looks like the query syntax is wrong, but I have checked with "php -l" and the message is that the syntax is ok, so what is wrong here ?

**EDIT 2**

Now I get to errors but the script is still not writing to the database.

The HTML FORM :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.select-to-autocomplete.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jsform.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery-ui.css">


    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="/form.php" method="post" id="register">
                <div>
                    <input placeholder="Type your Name" type="text" name="Name" id="Name" maxlength="50">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <input placeholder="Type your Surname" type="text" name="Surname" id="Surname"  maxlength="50">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <input placeholder="E-mail address" type="text" name="Mail" id="Mail" maxlength="50">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>

                    <input placeholder="Password" type="text" name="Pass" id="Pass" maxlength="50">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>

                    <input placeholder="Confirm Password" type="text" name="Cpass" id="Cpass" maxlength="50">
                </div>

                <br>
                <div>
                    <select placeholder="Type your country" name="Country" id="Country" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
                        <option value="Afghanistan" data-alternative-spellings="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                        <option value="Åland Islands" data-alternative-spellings="AX Aaland Aland" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Åland Islands</option>
                        <option value="Albania" data-alternative-
                        <option value="Luxembourg" data-alternative-spellings="LU">Luxembourg</option>
                        <option value="Macao" data-alternative-spellings="MO">Macao</option>
                        <option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic Of" data-alternative-spellings="MK">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic Of</option>
                        <option value="Madagascar" data-alternative-spellings="MG">Madagascar</option>
                        <option value="Malawi" data-alternative-spellings="MW">Malawi</option>
                        <option value="Malaysia" data-alternative-spellings="MY">Malaysia</option>
                        <option value="Maldives" data-alternative-spellings="MV">Maldives</option>
                        <option value="Mali" data-alternative-spellings="ML">Mali</option>
                        <option value="Malta" data-alternative-spellings="MT">Malta</option>
                        <option value="Marshall Islands" data-alternative-spellings="MH" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Marshall Islands</option>
                        <option value="Martinique" data-alternative-spellings="MQ">Martinique</option>
                        <option value="Mauritania" data-alternative-spellings="MR">Mauritania</option>
                        <option value="Mauritius" data-alternative-spellings="MU">Mauritius</option>
                        <option value="Mayotte" data-alternative-spellings="YT">Mayotte</option>
                        <option value="Mexico" data-alternative-spellings="MX Mexicanos" data-relevancy-booster="1.5">Mexico</option>
                        <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of" data-alternative-spellings="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
                        <option value="Moldova, Republic of" data-alternative-spellings="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
                        <option value="Monaco" data-alternative-spellings="MC">Monaco</option>
                        <option value="Mongolia" data-alternative-spellings="MN">Mongolia</option>
                        <option value="Montenegro" data-alternative-spellings="ME">Montenegro</option>
                        <option value="Montserrat" data-alternative-spellings="MS" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Montserrat</option>
                        <option value="Morocco" data-alternative-spellings="MA">Morocco</option>
                        <option value="Mozambique" data-alternative-spellings="MZ">Mozambique</option>
                        <option value="Myanmar" data-alternative-spellings="MM">Myanmar</option>
                        <option value="Namibia" data-alternative-spellings="NA">Namibia</option>
                        <option value="Nauru" data-alternative-spellings="NR" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Nauru</option>
                        <option value="Nepal" data-alternative-spellings="NP">Nepal</option>
                        <option value="Netherlands" data-alternative-spellings="NL Holland Nederland" data-relevancy-booster="1.5">Netherlands</option>
                        <option value="New Caledonia" data-alternative-spellings="NC" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">New Caledonia</option>
                        <option value="New Zealand" data-alternative-spellings="NZ">New Zealand</option>
                        <option value="Nicaragua" data-alternative-spellings="NI">Nicaragua</option>
                        <option value="Niger" data-alternative-spellings="NE">Niger</option>
                        <option value="Nigeria" data-alternative-spellings="NG" data-relevancy-booster="1.5">Nigeria</option>
                        <option value="Niue" data-alternative-spellings="NU" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Niue</option>
                        <option value="Norfolk Island" data-alternative-spellings="NF" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Norfolk Island</option>
                        <option value="Northern Mariana Islands" data-alternative-spellings="MP" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                        <option value="Norway" data-alternative-spellings="NO Norge Noreg" data-relevancy-booster="1.5">Norway</option>
                        <option value="Oman" data-alternative-spellings="OM">Oman</option>
                        <option value="Pakistan" data-alternative-spellings="PK" data-relevancy-booster="2">Pakistan</option>
                        <option value="Palau" data-alternative-spellings="PW" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Palau</option>
                        <option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied" data-alternative-spellings="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
                        <option value="Panama" data-alternative-spellings="PA">Panama</option>
                        <option value="Papua New Guinea" data-alternative-spellings="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
                        <option value="Paraguay" data-alternative-spellings="PY">Paraguay</option>
                        <option value="Peru" data-alternative-spellings="PE">Peru</option>
                        <option value="Philippines" data-alternative-spellings="PH" data-relevancy-booster="1.5">Philippines</option>
                        <option value="Pitcairn" data-alternative-spellings="PN" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Pitcairn</option>
                        <option value="Poland" data-alternative-spellings="PL" data-relevancy-booster="1.25">Poland</option>
                        <option value="Portugal" data-alternative-spellings="PT" data-relevancy-booster="1.5">Portugal</option>
                        <option value="Puerto Rico" data-alternative-spellings="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                        <option value="Qatar" data-alternative-spellings="QA">Qatar</option>
                        <option value="Réunion" data-alternative-spellings="RE Reunion">Réunion</option>
                        <option value="Romania" data-alternative-spellings="RO">Romania</option>
                        <option value="Russian Federation" data-alternative-spellings="RU Russia Rossiya" data-relevancy-booster="2.5">Russian Federation</option>
                        <option value="Rwanda" data-alternative-spellings="RW">Rwanda</option>
                        <option value="Saint Barthélemy" data-alternative-spellings="BL" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Saint Barthélemy</option>
                        <option value="Saint Helena" data-alternative-spellings="SH" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Saint Helena</option>
                        <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis" data-alternative-spellings="KN" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                        <option value="Saint Lucia" data-alternative-spellings="LC" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Saint Lucia</option>
                        <option value="Saint Martin (French Part)" data-alternative-spellings="MF" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Saint Martin (French Part)</option>
                        <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon" data-alternative-spellings="PM" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                        <option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" data-alternative-spellings="VC" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
                        <option value="Samoa" data-alternative-spellings="WS">Samoa</option>
                        <option value="San Marino" data-alternative-spellings="SM">San Marino</option>
                        <option value="Sao Tome and Principe" data-alternative-spellings="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                        <option value="Saudi Arabia" data-alternative-spellings="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
                        <option value="Senegal" data-alternative-spellings="SN">Senegal</option>
                        <option value="Serbia" data-alternative-spellings="RS">Serbia</option>
                        <option value="Seychelles" data-alternative-spellings="SC" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Seychelles</option>
                        <option value="Sierra Leone" data-alternative-spellings="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
                        <option value="Singapore" data-alternative-spellings="SG">Singapore</option>
                        <option value="Sint Maarten (Dutch Part)" data-alternative-spellings="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch Part)</option>
                        <option value="Slovakia" data-alternative-spellings="SK">Slovakia</option>
                        <option value="Slovenia" data-alternative-spellings="SI">Slovenia</option>
                        <option value="Solomon Islands" data-alternative-spellings="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
                        <option value="Somalia" data-alternative-spellings="SO">Somalia</option>
                        <option value="South Africa" data-alternative-spellings="ZA">South Africa</option>
                        <option value="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands" data-alternative-spellings="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
                        <option value="South Sudan" data-alternative-spellings="SS">South Sudan</option>
                        <option value="Spain" data-alternative-spellings="ES España" data-relevancy-booster="2">Spain</option>
                        <option value="Sri Lanka" data-alternative-spellings="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
                        <option value="Sudan" data-alternative-spellings="SD">Sudan</option>
                        <option value="Suriname" data-alternative-spellings="SR">Suriname</option>
                        <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen" data-alternative-spellings="SJ" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
                        <option value="Swaziland" data-alternative-spellings="SZ">Swaziland</option>
                        <option value="Sweden" data-alternative-spellings="SE Sverige" data-relevancy-booster="1.5">Sweden</option>
                        <option value="Switzerland" data-alternative-spellings="CH Swiss Confederation Schweiz Suisse Svizzera Svizra" data-relevancy-booster="1.5">Switzerland</option>
                        <option value="Syrian Arab Republic" data-alternative-spellings="SY Syria">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
                        <option value="Taiwan, Province of China" data-alternative-spellings="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
                        <option value="Tajikistan" data-alternative-spellings="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
                        <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of" data-alternative-spellings="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
                        <option value="Thailand" data-alternative-spellings="TH">Thailand</option>
                        <option value="Timor-Leste" data-alternative-spellings="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
                        <option value="Togo" data-alternative-spellings="TG">Togo</option>
                        <option value="Tokelau" data-alternative-spellings="TK" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Tokelau</option>
                        <option value="Tonga" data-alternative-spellings="TO">Tonga</option>
                        <option value="Trinidad and Tobago" data-alternative-spellings="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                        <option value="Tunisia" data-alternative-spellings="TN">Tunisia</option>
                        <option value="Turkey" data-alternative-spellings="TR Türkiye Turkiye">Turkey</option>
                        <option value="Turkmenistan" data-alternative-spellings="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
                        <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands" data-alternative-spellings="TC" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                        <option value="Tuvalu" data-alternative-spellings="TV" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Tuvalu</option>
                        <option value="Uganda" data-alternative-spellings="UG">Uganda</option>
                        <option value="Ukraine" data-alternative-spellings="UA Ukrayina">Ukraine</option>
                        <option value="United Arab Emirates" data-alternative-spellings="AE UAE Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                        <option value="United Kingdom" data-alternative-spellings="GB Great Britain England UK Wales Scotland Northern Ireland" data-relevancy-booster="2.5">United Kingdom</option>
                        <option value="United States" data-relevancy-booster="3.5" data-alternative-spellings="US USA United States of America">United States</option>
                        <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands" data-alternative-spellings="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                        <option value="Uruguay" data-alternative-spellings="UY">Uruguay</option>
                        <option value="Uzbekistan" data-alternative-spellings="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
                        <option value="Vanuatu" data-alternative-spellings="VU">Vanuatu</option>
                        <option value="Venezuela" data-alternative-spellings="VE">Venezuela</option>
                        <option value="Vietnam" data-alternative-spellings="VN" data-relevancy-booster="1.5">Vietnam</option>
                        <option value="Virgin Islands, British" data-alternative-spellings="VG" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Virgin Islands, British</option>
                        <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S." data-alternative-spellings="VI" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
                        <option value="Wallis and Futuna" data-alternative-spellings="WF" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Wallis and Futuna</option>
                        <option value="Western Sahara" data-alternative-spellings="EH">Western Sahara</option>
                        <option value="Yemen" data-alternative-spellings="YE">Yemen</option>
                        <option value="Zambia" data-alternative-spellings="ZM">Zambia</option>
                        <option value="Zimbabwe" data-alternative-spellings="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
                <br>
                <div>

                    <input placeholder="City" type="text" name="City" id="City" maxlength="50">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>

                    <input placeholder="Complete Address" type="text" name="Address" id="Address" maxlength="50">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>

                    <input placeholder="P.O Box" type="text" name="PO" id="PO" maxlength="50">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" name="fSubmit" id="fSubmit" value="Submit">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

db connection variables script

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxx";
$dbname = "mlp";
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
?>
```

Comment: u wanna cram VALUES in like )VALUES ?

Comment: You'd need to put backticks around the column and table names, not single quotes. also throw `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as the very first thing in your script

Comment: @DrewPierce that's not a syntax error and works fine.

Comment: add `$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. that will tell you if there's any errors in your DB - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Make sure all files are within scope.

Comment: Thank you Fredd-ii- this is the output : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' (`name`, `password`, `email` ) VALUES ('x', 'passwordXX', 'xavier@gm' at line 1
Notice: Undefined variable: count in /home/xavier/mylimitedprint/form.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined variable: count in /home/xavier/mylimitedprint/form.php on line 34
Number of rows added:

Comment: you're welcome. Now that error is because you need to remove the single quotes from `INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'password', 'email')` so it read as `INSERT INTO users (name, password, email)` or use ticks as shown in the error below, being `\`` - those resemble quotes but they are not the same. Once you've removed them, keep error exceptions where you have it now as I suggested. If there are more errors after that, let me know.

Comment: I have it like this already $sql = "INSERT INTO 'users' (`name`, `password`, `email` ) VALUES ('$varName', '$varPass', '$varMail')";  I changed that before.

Comment: Okay It works now :) Thank you for the extra debug and help. It works by just not adding ticks or single quotes to the table name or columns !

Comment: @PythPhytho I appreciate the vote of thanks. I see you've good manners and that's important in this world ;-) *cheers*

Comment: it should work absolutely fine with backticks around the table and column names, just not the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem:

**You declared `$STH` instead of `$sql`.**

To fix this:

1. Change `$STH = ...` to `$sql = ...`

OR

2. Change `$count = $DBH->exec($sql);` to `$count = $DBH->exec($STH);`

I'd recommend the first one.

---

Also, you should really consider using [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection.

---

Also:

```
$STH = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'password', 'email' )"
                . "VALUES ('$varName', '$varPass', '$varMail')";
```

This results in:

```
INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'password', 'email' )VALUES ('$varName', '$varPass', '$varMail')
```

There are a couple of other things wrong with this:

1. There's no space between `)` and `VALUES`
2. The column names have quotes around them instead of backticks
3. There's really no point in that string concatenation, just put it all in one string.

The fix: (edited)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, password, email) VALUES ('$varName', '$varPass', '$varMail')";
```

Comment: There doesn't need to be a space between `)` and `values`

Comment: I am still getting the same error, now on line 21. That doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @PythPhytho did you follow the instructions at the top?

Comment: I have changed STH for sql and now I don't get any errors but the rows counter part of the script doesn't output anything, so I guess it is still not writing to the database

Comment: I just checked and there is nothing written on those columns

Comment: @PythPhytho you need to change `'users'` to `\`users\``

Comment: it works by just not surrounding with any quotes neither the table or column names, otherwise it throws a mysql syntax violation. I don't really know why as I am pretty new to it. Fred-ii- answer for insight. Thank you !

Comment: It actually didn't because by changing single quotes by backticks I still had a mysql syntax violation. The solution is to just not surround the table or columns with quotes or backticks.

Comment: @PythPhytho I removed the "by Fred". I should have never touched the answer in the first place. It wasn't my job to do so and was my mistake on my part; improving an answer doesn't always go well. I won't be doing that again. Live and learn.

Comment: @Fred-ii- editing the answer to fix the solution isn't bad, just adding things like that is unnecessary -- especially since [we can see this](http://puu.sh/ibBsa/c9a7dca343.png).